# Processing window tilted

Tags: processing

So i made this simple 2D game in processing and problem is that when i run it whole game is tilted to left a little so it have empty space on right and is cropped on left. Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

This is code:

```
int red = 20;
 int kolona = 20;
 boolean[][] grid = new boolean[red][kolona]; 
 int playerIndexX = 10;
  int playerIndexY = 10;
void setup() {
  size(300, 300);
  for(int i = 0; i < red; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < kolona; j++)
    {
      if(random(100) < 20 && j != 50 && i != 20)
      {
        grid[i][j] = true;
      }
    }
  }
  rectMode(CENTER);
}
void keyPressed()
{
  if(keyCode == DOWN && playerIndexY + 1 < 20 && !grid[playerIndexX][playerIndexY+1])
  {
    playerIndexY++;
  }
  if(keyCode == UP && playerIndexY - 1 >= 0 && !grid[playerIndexX][playerIndexY- 1])
  {
    playerIndexY--;
  }
  if(keyCode == LEFT && playerIndexX - 1 >= 0 && !grid[playerIndexX-1][playerIndexY])
  {
    playerIndexX--;
  }
  if(keyCode == RIGHT && playerIndexX + 1 < 20 && !grid[playerIndexX+1][playerIndexY])
  {
    playerIndexX++;
  }
}
void draw() {
  int kockaWidth = width/red;
  int kockaHeight = height/kolona;
  for(int i = 0; i < red; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < kolona; j++)
    {
      if(grid[i][j])
      {
        fill(255,0,0);
        rect(kockaWidth * i, kockaHeight *j, kockaWidth,kockaHeight);
      }
      else
      {
       stroke(1);
       fill(160,160,160);
       rect(kockaWidth * i, kockaHeight *j, kockaWidth,kockaHeight);
      }
    }
  }
  float playerPixelX = playerIndexX * kockaWidth;
  float playerPixelY = playerIndexY * kockaHeight;
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  rect(playerPixelX, playerPixelY, kockaWidth, kockaHeight);
  
  
}
```

Grid should cover whole screen but for some reason it is tilted and i dont think this is because of code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [`rectMode`](https://processing.org/reference/rectMode_.html) `CORNER` instead of `CENTER` for drawing the rectangles:

<s>`rectMode(CENTER);`</s>

```java
rectMode(CORNER);
```